# How to insert a query calculation into a column/attribute of an already existing entity?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, entity

So I had created a query which was used to calculate sales staff commission this gave me the expected result which I needed , so the next thing i needed to do was to insert these calculated values into my staff entity, at present remain NULL, but the issue was how do I place this statement to fill up the rows of the staff table, I saw many places about how to update a table column content

I just want to know how can i send the commission column to another entity's column
So from this query it lists out the commission for each and every staff member, but how can I insert all these commissions into the column of another entity like staff

Comment: Do you mean "How can I UPDATE the Staff row with the result of this calculation"?

Comment: Don't use "natural join"!  It is not "natural", depending on common names between tables.  It doesn't even make use of properly declared foreign key relationships.  Use an `on` or `using` clause so it is clear what the query is doing.  In addition, your question should have the query as text.  Sample data and desired results would help.  And it is quite unclear where what `set` is as a table and where `commission` comes from.  Qualify *all* column references.

Comment: I'll update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the table `staff` with a join to your query (without the `ORDER BY` clause):

```
update staff s
inner join (
  <your query>
) t on t.staffID = s.staffID
set s.columnname = t.Commission
```

Change `columnname` to the name of the column that you want to update.
Also in your query it's safer to `GROUP BY staffID, staffName` just in case there are 2 staff members with the same name.

Comment: Hi but i'm getting an error called: Unknown column 't.Commision' in 'field list'

Comment: Your query returns a column aliased as Commission. I think I misspelled it, I missed the double s.  I edited.